# Open Graph tags not working in WordPress/Codeigniter integration

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-opengraph

My website is [wpci-dev.com](http://wpci-dev.com). I have integrated a Codeigniter web application with WordPress. In the WordPress theme header, I have placed these meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="RealConnect Dev Site"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://wpci-dev.com"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="This is a development site for Birch Studio Graphic's RealConnect web application."/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://wpci-dev.com/images/BSGlogoBLK.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
```

If I use the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) with wpci-dev.com, the scraper picks up my meta tags and displays the content correctly when shared. I can also check wpci-dev.com/about-us/ with the debugger and get the correct results.

The problem is when I try to share a page that is rendered using Codeigniter - wpci-dev.com/details/residential/449153/, the open graph tags are not being scraped:

[image: Object debugger response]

If I click on the "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" link, It displays a white page with the text "Document returned no data":

[image: Scraper response]

We developed another site, [MyCAAR.com](http://mycaar.com), which is built completely in Codeigniter (no WordPress), and the open graph tags work correctly for all of the pages. So, I don't think this is a Codeigniter issue. I think it has something to do with the Codeigniter/WordPress integration.

I have searched far and wide for answers to this issue with no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like your server is returning bad stuff.

Comment: Yes, on the codeigniter rendered pages, but not on the pages that are rendered by WordPress. I just checked the error log and I don't see any errors. Could it still be a server issue?

Comment: http://wpci-dev.com/details/residential/449153/ returns an HTTP status code 404 Not Found, even when requested via a normal browser.

Comment: But, you can still navigate to the page and see the content.

Comment: What does that have to do with anything? Your server explicitly tells every HTTP client that the requested content does not exist. The fact that common browsers still display the HTTP response body content in such cases doesn’t change that one bit (and they only do so, because it is supposed to contain an error message readable by humans.)

Comment: @CBroe Okay. Thank you. Now I see what you are saying. In fact, the pages displayed are not WordPress pages, so it makes sense that they would return a 404 response. Now I know the problem. Could you please answer this question so I can mark your response as answered. I hope you didn't down vote my question just because I was communicating back anf forth with you about the HTTP response. This is not a common integration, so sometimes it's hard to see answers that are right in front of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wpci-dev.com/details/residential/449153/ returns an HTTP status code `404 Not Found`, even when requested via a normal browser. Therefor, the Facebook scraper will consider this an error, and not take any OG meta data from the source, even if it should be in fact present.

Your server explicitly tells every HTTP client that the requested content does not exist. The fact that common browsers still display the HTTP response body content in such cases doesn’t change that one bit (and they only do so, because it is supposed to contain an error message readable by humans.)

So you’ll need to investigate *why* these page(s) are served with a 404 status code, and fix it to return a “normal” `200 OK`. (Specifics will depend on how exactly your WP/CI integration works and what it does.)